# Template loading jQuery twice, removing either versions breaks the site

Tags: templates, jquery

I am working on the following site: https://www.jls-concept.fr/
The template is loading jQuery twice:
 - once from Joomla: https://www.jls-concept.fr/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js
 - and another time here: https://www.jls-concept.fr/templates/superfine/assets/js/assets.min.js

where the template author wisely decided to put the minification of several javascript libraries there.

I have tried removing the extra jQuery in assets file, but the site stops working.

I tried changing the content of both js files, trying to make both load the same version but to no avail.

I don't have much expertise with joomla nor frontend.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue may be that Joomla's jQuery is set no noconflict mode. Adding the second instance of jQuery is then probably allowing scripts to  us `$` as a jQuery reference.

Try removing the template's jQuery code and adding the following in its place:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

This should mean subsequent scripts can once again use the dollar to represent jQuery.

If that doesn't work, try looking at your console (F12) to see what javascript errors are being thrown.  Adding this to your question may help locate the source of the problem.

Comment: It seems like the assets file can't read the jquery included by joomla.
I have removed the jQuery included by the template and I added what you suggested.
This is what I got. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined
    at assets.min.js:7`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `index.php` in your template you can add this. It will remove Joomla! instance of jQuery.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
unset($document->_scripts['media/jui/js/jquery.min.js']);
```

Just make sure that you still gonna have jQuery loaded before any other scripts that require jQuery (in this case the `assets.min.js`).

You can also try to search for uncompressed version of `assets.min.js` and then remove the jQuery. Or decompress it using tool like [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and then remove it.